# Adding tabs with roles inside custom app in Microsoft teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have added custom app in Microsoft teams. Currently, there are three tabs abc, chat and about. I need to hide abc tab from users.it should be visible only to Admin.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

User-role based hiding tabs are not supported currently. You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).